# How to enable two network interfaces both for internet in ubuntu12.04

Tags: networking, ubuntu

My physical server has two interfaces: eth0 and eth1. I intend to enable the two network interfaces both for internet in ubuntu12.04. I configure the /etc/network/interfaces as below:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 10.10.101.105
gateway 10.10.101.254
netmask 255.255.255.0
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
address 10.10.101.205
gateway 10.10.101.254
netmask 255.255.255.0
```

And the output of ifconfig is shown below:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr e0:db:55:25:ed:10
          inet addr:10.10.101.105  Bcast:10.10.101.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::e2db:55ff:fe25:ed10/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1148531 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:554215 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:1636019748 (1.6 GB)  TX bytes:40068201 (40.0 MB)
          Interrupt:35

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr e0:db:55:25:ed:11
          inet addr:10.10.101.205  Bcast:10.10.101.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::e2db:55ff:fe25:ed11/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:56699 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:6 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:4077879 (4.0 MB)  TX bytes:492 (492.0 B)
          Interrupt:38

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:124891 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:124891 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:1484482588 (1.4 GB)  TX bytes:1484482588 (1.4 GB)
```

So, I think both the 2 network interfaces are up. However, I find I can access my physical server only via eth0(10.10.101.105), and fail to access it via eth1(10.10.101.205).

When I use `route -n` to check the router table in my server, it shows:

```
vli05@vli05:~$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.10.101.254   0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0
10.10.101.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
10.10.101.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
```

I could not find any thing wrong. Could you please give me some ideas? Thanks.

Comment: You may want to ask this question at [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/) or [Unix & LInux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on askubuntu.com

Comment: The question seems fine and on-topic to me. You might get better help at [AskUbuntu](http://askubuntu.com/), but it is also fine here.

Comment: It might be a bit dated by now: But how are you trying to access the host? From the 10.10.101.0/24 LAN via a PC which has the first NICs ARP in its cache?